# Is it safe to pass context as dependency in ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, memory-leaks

I am passing SessionManager as a Dependency that requires context in my ViewModel

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ListingsViewModelFactory(
        ListingsModel(1),
        SessionManager(
            requireContext(), <===== HERE
            JsonEncoder(),
            JsonDecoder()),
        Validator(),
        WebService(),
        JsonEncoder(),
        JsonDecoder()
    )
    ).get(ListingsViewModel::class.java)
```

we know that passing **context** to ViewModel is a bad practice that should cause memory leaks.

1. So can we pass context in dependency in ViewModel like currently, I'm passing in **SessionManager**?
2. Passing context in Dependency in ViewModel causes memory leaks?

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `requireContext()` in a Fragment, it is actually getting the Activity instance, and passing that to the ViewModel will leak the Activity.

It is safe to pass the application Context, because that is a single instance for the lifetime of your application.

So replace `requireContext()` with `requireContext().applicationContext`, and it is fine.

It seems a bit odd that you are instantiating your JsonEncoder and Decoder twice, but maybe it's OK with your logic. You might want to check that.

Comment: Means passing activity context to one of the dependency of ViewModel (ViewModel(SessionManager(requireContext)) is exactly the same as passing context to ViewModel itself (ViewModel(requireContext)), in both case it will leak memory until we pass applicationContext, is am right?

Comment: Yes, either way would leak the Activity.

Comment: I am accessing sharedPreference in SessionManager that required context, what you’ll suggest the best way to access preferences in my SessionManager?

Comment: You can provide application context to your session manager using DI frameworks, e.g. Dagger 2. Long story short, it will build DI container that will provide your app context to the entities requiring it. 
Also, application context is the best match to initialize and access shared preferences

Comment: DI framework will also keep you from need for passing the context via constructor

Answer (score 1):

I assume it depends on the type of context. Since the lifetime of a ViewModel is longer than the lifetime of the view it refers to, passing Activity can cause memory leak.

However, the lifetime of a ViewModel cannot be longer than the lifetime of the application. So the passing of Application should be fine.

Comment: Means we should not pass activity context to the dependency of ViewModel, it would cause memory leaks, right?

Comment: Also is it good practice to pass applicationContext to ViewModel, in terms of Testing?

Comment: In terms of testing you probably will not face any difficulties, since the context you pass will be mocked object